# Issue with new table in oracle

Tags: database, oracle, database-design, relational-database, oracle12c

I have to add a new table according to some new requirements, the model currently consists of two tables: `DETAIL` and `SUMMARY`.

The relation is that every detail has associated one summary, so now I need to add a new table called `SUMMARY_ESP`, which has the a `FK ( SUMMARY)` and two more columns, something like this:

```
ID | SUMMARY_ID | ESP_ID | PRIORITY_ESP | PTY_ID | PRIORITY_PTY
1  |  123       |   34   |    1         |   122  |      1  
2  |  123       |   35   |    2         |   111  |      2
3  |  123       |   30   |    3         | null   |      null
4  |  1111      |   34   |    4         | null   |      null
```

Other tables info:

```
DETAIL TABLE
    ID_DET | AMOUNT |      DATE    | ID_SUMMARY | EXTERNAL_ID
    1      |  1000  |   14/05/2018 |    1111    |     4
    2      |  2000  |   18/07/2016 |    1111    |     4
    3      |  1200  |   11/07/2017 |    123     |     1
    4      |  1300  |   21/09/2018 |    123     |     2



SUMMARY TABLE
        ID_SUMMARY | PRIORITY| PROFILE | CLASS | AREA
        123        |  1      |   1     |    5  |   3     
        1111       |  2      |   1     |    5  |   3   
        33         |  3      |   2     |    5  |   9   
        4          |  4      |   8     |    5  |   10
```

So according to this, `SUMMARY_ID` , `ESP_ID` and `PTY_ID` are unique, the thing is at some point to know the what is the `ESP_ID` of certain detail, but since the relation is with `SUMMARY` table, I have no idea which one was when it was added, so I was asked to create a new column to the `DETAIL` table called `EXTERNAL_ID`, so I can know what is the code from the `SUMMARY_ESP`.

So if the row is the first one, it can be either `24` or `122` in the new column according to some previous logic, but I'm worried about the implications this might have in the future, because somehow I might be duplicating information, also I would need to make some weird logic in order to get the priority depending on whether it's `ESP_ID` or `PTY_ID`.

The new table along with `SUMMARY` are somehow parameters table, their values do not change that often and only the `PRIORITY` column would change, `DETAIL` instead is more transactional, and it has insert and update everyday according to some business logic.

I was thinking of adding the ID of the new table as a FK to the `DETAIL` table, but at the end would be the same, because it'll be hard to maintain and update would be harder, also it's like a circular dependency, so I'm kind of stuck with this , so any kind of help would be really helpful, below the complete model, with the current idea.

Also I can't add those new columns to the table `SUMMARY`, because there could be more than one associated to the same code in that table and since it's the PK I cant add two rows with the same code.

[image]

Comment: It would be more helpful if you could edit your question to include the sample data for the two existing tables as text.

Comment: done, i just include sample data for the  existing tables

Comment: Does the sample data for the existing tables match the desired output? In order for us to be able to help you, we need to be able to take the input data and use it to match the required output.

Comment: Yes, it does, there are some other columns I did not include which are not relevant, those data is the same I have in my local database, the only thing I dont have is the EXTERNAL_ID , but that's the one I'm trying to figure out , so I have it as an example, and how the relation should be , but as I said in my opinion is not the best solution

Answer (score 0):

> The relation is that every detail has associated one summary

You need to represent that relationship in your database layout : if you  have a 1-N relationship between `SUMMARY` and `DETAIL`, you want to create another column in `DETAIL` that holds the primary key of the `SUMMARY` record that it is related to.

With this relation in place, you can start from a `DETAIL` row, relate a row from `SUMMARY` and identifiy all `SUMMARY_ESP` records that are linked to it.

Now if you need to uniquely relate a `DETAIL` record to a `SUMMARY_ESP` record, then you want to either add a foreign key to `SUMMARY_ESP` in `DETAIL`, or the other way around (add a foreign key to `DETAIL` in `SUMMARY_ESP`), depending on the way your data flows.

Comment: I get your point, but since the requirement is like that and the new data could repeat, I cant' add the new columns to none of those tables, because as I said in SUMMARY, the ID could be twice and that's the PK and in DETAIL, well it means that if there are 3000 rows related to one row of the new table, the new 4 columns will have the same information, so changing the priority would be harder, instead of only doing it on one row

Comment: Thanks for your comment, that's what I was planning at first, but when I realized that there could be two rows in SUMMARY_ESP with the same ID I knew this solution would bring me problems, because according to the model and samples if the SUMMARY_ID is 123 in detail and I need to know the PRIORITY from SUMMARY_ESP I can't know find that info, because in that table there's three with 123, so at that point I can't tell what was the row from SUMMARY_ESP that was related to DETAIL and that's somehow what I'll need in the future